# Java program file not found

Tags: java, filepath, filenotfoundexception, eof

I have looked through questions that have been posted here regarding this problem, and none of the solutions have been helpful.  I found a link to this page  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29
also, not helpful.  I have looked through my text book, even copied a similar code straight from the book, and was again given the File Not Found Exception.  The input.txt file is in the same folder as the program file, and I tried to use a specific path, also added this line to the code System.out.println(new File("C:/input.txt").getAbsolutePath());
it also did not help.  I feel like I have more questions now than answers. The name of the file is correct, and case is correct.  I did find that the .txt files are being saved in Word, so I went there and changed the format to plain txt file.  Does it being saved as a Word document have something to do with this problem, or am I wasting time there?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class FileRead
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        double count = 0;
        double sum = count++;
        double average = sum/count;

        File fileObject = new File("C:/input.txt");
        System.out.println(new File("C:/input.txt").getAbsolutePath());
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner (fileObject);

        while (fileIn.hasNext())
        {
            count = fileIn.nextDouble();
            sum = count++;
        }
        average = sum/count;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
        System.out.println("The total of the: " + count + "numbers entered are: "
            + sum + " and the average is: " + df.format(average));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you secure that your document has the extension .txt? Notice that it can be `input.txt.docx` as you said you created the file in Word. To be secure about this configure your folder to see the extension of all files.

Comment: actually, I created the file in texpad, but for some reason it is saving it in Word?  but it does have the extension .txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C:/input.txt` is telling the file system to look for a file called input.txt at the root of the hard drive, assuming `C:/` is equivalent to `C:\`.
Is this where you are running the program in the root directory.  If not, and there is no file called input.txt in the root director the program won't work as expected.

Try changing the the code as described by BlackCode, and/or removing the `C:/`

Typing `pwd` in a command window will tell you what directly you are in, and if its not the root of your hard drive the program can not find the file you are telling it too look for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the slash: "C://input.txt".

Comment: No - only the backslash needs to be escaped - that is a forward slash

Answer (score 0):

"The input.txt file is in the same folder as the program file": that means you only need "input.txt"

To see the files exactly with the names saved you can go to the command window and type dir at the location where you are looking for.

Alternately you can do that from within the program:

```
File f=new File(".");
String[] fs=f.list();
for(String s:fs) System.out.println(s);
```

If your file doesnt print then it's somewhere else.

Comment: That's what I thought too.  I'm trying to add a try and catch statement now, but it doesn't like that either.

Comment: then there is only one way: go to the command window and type dir at the program location; you will see all the files exactly as saved

Comment: I did this, and the file comes up in the list, I added the code to the program, and there it was.... I just don't understand why it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

In file path change "/" to File.separator
Example:

```
    File fileObject = new File("C:" + File.separator + "input.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine and it works fine on my Window 7 (although I had to change to administrator to create the c:\input.txt)
It is confusing that .getAbsolutePath() gives a value even if the file does not exist.
A better test is the following - it will print false if your file does not exist.

```
File fileObject = new File("c:/input.txt");
System.out.println(fileObject.exists());
Scanner fileIn = new Scanner (fileObject);
```

To be certain the file exists try this at the command line

```
echo 1 2 3 4 > input.txt
```

Then get rid of the full path and just use "input.txt" as the file name.

Comment: I tried this, it still says it can not find it... I know it is there, as I keep looking to make sure I am not hallucinating the fact that I created it.

Comment: If you are certain that your input file is in the same folder as your executable then there is no need for the c:/ at the start. Are you using Eclipse or are you compiling from the command line?

Comment: using JDK I got it from here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/  it is what the instructor sent us, now I realize there are literally tons of compilers out there, this is the one I guess we are supposed to use though.

Comment: Well, your code runs fine, I tried it. The only explanation is that the file is not where you think it is. Try changing the input file name to something you know must exist - "FileRead.java" no slashes no c: You will at least get an error message in a different place. If it is any consolation - I've been where you are many times.

Answer (score -1):

Use this :

Scanner fileIn = new Scanner ("C:/input.txt");

Comment: That gives a new error, I misread the first time, so when I tried that it says inputMismatchException.